# Ruby on rails-->Mysql2::Error Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

Hi 
I just started on Ruby on Rails. I try to launch my first 'HelloWorld' app using WebRick and MySQL 5.5, Windows XP

In firefox I can see the Rails standart page on "localhost:3000" but if I click on the link "about your apps environment" or try to see a pretty basic "hello world" page on localhost:3000/demo/index/ i get the error(after a minute or 2)

"Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0.

Rails 3.0.7
MySQL 5.5
Gem 1.8.1
Ruby 1.9.2p180
Win XP 32
Tried both mysql and mysql2 gems on various versions.
The database seems to work fine through the console.
Tried also to connect with no password
Using utf8 and stating that in the database.yml.
tried https://github.com/ghazel/mysql2/commit/a9515ed75f3b7a7ce2813a364a0e7ede66394a41
tried to turn off firewalls completely

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_db
  pool: 5
  username: simple
  password: 
  host: localhost
  port: 3000
```

Help me!!!! So frustrated.....

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to connect your MySQL connection to the Mongrel socket, so that's not going to work very well, as your application will just call itself when trying to make a database call.

You should probably change that to the default port 3306, or just leave it out and let the configuration defaults come into play.

Comment: i had given port 80 so it didn't work... nd changed to 3306 and it's working fine